# Queue trigger in azure apparently not clearing up after succesful functions run

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I am very new to Azure so I am not sure if my question is stated correctly but I will do my best:

I have an App that sends data in the form (1.bin, 2.bin, 3.bin...) always in consecutive order to a blob input container, when this happens it triggers an Azure function via QueueTrigger and the output of the function (1output.bin, 2output.bin, 3output.bin...) is stored in a blog output container.

When azure crashes the program tries 5 times before giving up. When azure succeeds it will run just once and that's it.

I am not sure what happened last week but since last week after each successful run, functions is idle like for 7 minutes and then it starts the process again as if it was the first time. So for example the blob receives 22.bin and functions process 22.bin and generates 22output.bin, it is supossed to stop after that but after seven minutes is processing 22.bin again.

I don't think is the app because each time the app sends data, even if it is the same one it will name the data with the next number (in my example 23.bin) but this is not the case it is just doing 22.bin again as if the trigger queue was not clear after the successful azure run, and it keeps doing it over and over again until I have to stop functions and make it crash i order to stop it.

Any idea in why is this happening and what can I try to correct it is greatly appreciated. I am just starting to learn about all this stuff.

Comment: Is it possible you have double-queued a job? I've had that happen before. Additionally, are your jobs idempotent? That is important to handle a lot of these types of concerns because even if you don't double-queue a job, it's possible for the job to run twice. For example, imagine it runs to 99% completion when the CPU blows up that it's running on - it'll later run again with the same side-effects. (Many other examples exist as well)

Comment: I am checking but I don't think id double queuing, I have a test signal that sends a test bin when I press run in the azure functions, and when I press that one the output is obtained and not repetition is being made.

Comment: Maybe post your code?

Comment: Please check [Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) tab for any errors. Also, you can find more details with [AppInsights](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/)

Comment: The Azure Storage Explorer is a great tool to inspect what is actually in your Queues to have a better idea of how many messages were actually sent through. If you're not looking there, you should. http://storageexplorer.com/

Comment: According to your description, we couldn't directly find the reason and solution. Could you please post more relevant codes about your queue trigger?

Comment: Thank you all for your tips, I am currently following your advice and will update as soon as anything new comes up for all to know

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could be possibly happening is that, the function execution time is exceeding 5 mins. Since this is a hard limit, function runtime would terminate the current execution and restart the function host.

One way to test this would be to create a Function app using Standard App Service plan instead of Consumption plan. Function app created with standard plan does not have execution time limit. You can log function start time and end time to see if it is taking longer than 5 mins to complete processing queue message.

Comment: The function is indeed taking longer than 5 minutes, but we are using standard plan instead of consumption. Two weeks ago we did not have the problem and we were using functions for months.

Comment: Can you enable Always on" from application settings. You need it for executions longer than 5 minutes in a standard plan.